# Vue 3 browser caching doesnt pick latest files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, browser-cache

We have a build.js code in our project which makes a duplicate of our client directory and adds a folder inside src.

example -
`client/src/components` will become `dist/src/abcxy/components`

abcxy will change every time we create a new build.

Now the problem is that the browser tries to find the old dist files from the cache and is unable to find them, instead of finding new files it gives an error in the console.

The error changes depending on the browser I am using

EXAMPLE ERROR - Failed to load ‘http://localhost/src/pbtsg/components/report/reports.js’. A ServiceWorker intercepted the request and encountered an unexpected error.

Comment: Have you tried without the service worker? Are you sure that the HTML file which tries to load these JS files is the new one after each build?

Comment: Make sure that `index.html` is updated to load the new files. It has no reason to load these cached files unless requested, which means the references for the new scripts are not updated.

Comment: index.html updates on reload and once the user reloads, dist files update too. But the problem occurs if the user doesn't reload and navigates to different modules which will give the error.